# How to assign string value in C from void *?

Tags: c, string, struct, void-pointers

I'm implementing a `CMap` in C, and part of this entails storing information in a linked-list type of structure that I manually manage the memory of. So the first 4 bytes of this `struct` is a pointer to the next `struct`, the next section is the string (key), and the final section is the value.

Say `void *e = ptr` defines one such linked list.
Then, `ptr + 4` refers to the beginning of the string section.
I want to assign that string value to another string, and what I've done so far is:

```
char *string = (char *)ptr + 4;
```

However, I don't think this is right.

Comment: Why can't you cast to the struct and then use the `->` operator to access the field?

Comment: How do you know the length of the string? It is terminated by a zero bytes? And what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to make a copy of the string? Or just access it? If it's a zero-terminated C-style string, and you just want to access its value, `char *string=(char *)ptr + 4;` is fine. (Though `sizeof(void *)` would be better than 4 -- the code may eventually need to run on an LP64 platform.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to point to the same string your code is fine, assuming pointers are always 4 bytes wide.

If you want to copy the contents of the string use malloc and strcpy to create a new string.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference struct instead of calculating offsets.

```
//if data is structured this way
struct struct_list_el
{
  struct list_el * next; 
  char* str;
  int value;
};
typedef struct struct_list_el list_el;

// than from void_pointer
list_el* el;
el = (list_el*) void_pointer;

char * string;
string = el->str;
```

Comment: If you use a struct you should make sure everything is properly aligned in memory, or you get a bus error on some architectures (for example m68k).

Comment: @hochl What? difference with m68k is that they are big endian, where PC is little endian. That mean than sending integer from one machine to another can cause problems.

Comment: I remember that on m68000, accessing anything larger than a byte at an un-even address will give a bus error, but that was in the 80s, maybe the newer models do not give a bus error in such situations and split the memory access into two accesses internally. Anyways, a compiler usually inserts padding bytes so that all structure members are at an accessible offset (usually even for anything but a byte).

Comment: You can use macro #pragma pack(1) to pack structure. I have no problems using this approach on coldfire.

Answer (score 0):

@ralu is right that you should be using a struct. But you should also be very careful when copying strings. In C there is no first-class string object like in C++, Java, Python, and well, everything else. :)

In C, character pointers (`char*`) are often used as strings, but they are really just pointers to null-terminated arrays of bytes in memory somewhere. Copying a character pointer is not the same as copying the underlying array of characters. To do that, you need to provide memory for the characters of the copy. This memory can be on the stack (a local array), or the heap (created with malloc), or some other buffer.

You'll need to measure the length of the string before you do anything to make sure that the target buffer can hold it. Be sure to add one to the length so that there is room for the terminating null.

Also note that the standard library functions (strlen, strcpy, strncpy, strcat, snprintf, strdup, etc.) are slightly incompatible with each other regarding the terminating null. For example, strlen returns the number of characters, excluding the terminating null, so buffers need to be one byte larger than what it returns to hold things. Also, strncpy does not guarantee null termination while snprintf does. Misuse of these functions and C strings in general is the cause of a significant number of security breaches (not to mention bugs) in computer systems today.

Unless you build or use a solid library, string and list manipulation in C is tedious and error-prone. You can see why C++ and all those other languages were invented.